# Change the placeholder when the select option is changed using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange

I have a site with the same form in different spots on the page. I would like to be able to have a placeholder in a text input change when I change the select option. I have a JSFiddle with a kinda example: http://jsfiddle.net/y1jhhqLz/

All the forms look like this:

```
<form id="form1">
    <select id="mySelect1" onClick="changePlaceHolder('#mySelect1','#myInput1')">
        <option value='-1'>Form 1</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput1" type="text" placeholder="Form 1"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form>
```

And in this example, I would like to have the place holder change on the input with the id myInput, when I select the option Third.

I have tried many different ways to include the most recent attempt, which I put on the JSFiddle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use jQuery to bind event http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Lg55vxm6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set select onclick attribute to

```
onclick="changePlaceHolder(this,'#myInput1');"
```

and change javascript function to

```
function changePlaceHolder(dropdown, element) {
    if (jQuery(dropdown).val() == "Third") {
         jQuery(element).attr('placeholder', 'You did it correctly!');   
    } else {
         jQuery(element).at}tr('placeholder', '');   
    }
}
```

in JSFiddle, you should set the loading behaviour to "no wrap - in head"

[image]

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Add a change listener to the select, then get the value of the select and set the attribute placeholder to said value:

```js
$('select').on('change',function(){
    var place=$(this).val();
  var num=$(this).attr('id').substring(8);
    $('#myInput'+num).attr('placeholder',place);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>How do I get it so that when I click on the option that says Third Choice (for any form), it will put in the text box (with the form and number ) a placeholder: "You did it correctly"? But it shouldn't change any other form but the one where you change the select to the Third Choice option. I tried using a onClick function.
</p>
<br><br>
    <h2>Please pick the third option from Form 1:</h2>
<form id="form1">
    <select id="mySelect1" onClick="changePlaceHolder('#mySelect1','#myInput1')">
        <option value='-1'>Form 1</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput1" type="text" placeholder="Form 1"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form>

<form id="form2">
    <select id="mySelect2">
        <option value='-2'>Form 2</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput2" type="text" placeholder="Form 2"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form>

<form id="form3">
    <select id="mySelect3">
        <option value='-3'>Form 3</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput3" type="text" placeholder="Form 3"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Even you can do it by on click as well like:

Answer (score 0):

Several things going on. First, remove the `onClick` events (we are not looking for when the `select` is clicked but rather when it is changed) and instead use jQuery's `on` method. Now `changePlaceHolder` has access to `this` which is the actual `select` box which was changed.

See below:

```js
jQuery('select').on('change input', changePlaceHolder);

function changePlaceHolder() {
    //I have to use jQuery instead of $ because it is on a wordpress site
    if (jQuery(this).val() == "Third") {
        jQuery(this).next().attr("placeholder","You did it correctly!");
    } else {
        jQuery(this).next().attr("placeholder"," ");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <h2>Please pick the third option from Form 1:</h2>
<form id="form1">
    <select id="mySelect1" >
        <option value='-1'>Form 1</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput1" type="text" placeholder="Form 1"/>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"/>
</form>
```

Other things to note: your `<input>` tags to not require an ending tag `</input>`, instead write them like this `<input />`. Note that the "/" ends the tag. You want to edit the input immediately following your select, in which case you can use `jQuery(this).next()` which will select the element immediately following the current `this` element.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case I would not touch source code, would define all functionality in script. Setting the `onlick` event inline is not a good idea, scripts should not go together with content.

I wrote this script having in mind that your `select` and `input` tags do not have to be siblings, the only condition is that both belong to same form:

```js
/* This way you can use $ in your Wordpress */
(function ($) {
    $('select').on('change', function(e) {
        var thisSelect = $(this);
        var thisSelectValue = thisSelect.val();
        var thisInput = thisSelect.closest('form').find('input[id^=myInput]');
        if (thisSelectValue == 'Third') {
            thisInput.attr("placeholder", "You did it correctly!");
        } else {
            thisInput.attr("placeholder", "");
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
p {
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Please pick the third option from Form 1:</h2>
<form id="form1">
    <select id="mySelect1">
        <option value='-1'>Form 1</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput1" type="text" placeholder="Form 1"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form>

<form id="form2">
    <select id="mySelect2">
        <option value='-2'>Form 2</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput2" type="text" placeholder="Form 2"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form>

<form id="form3">
    <select id="mySelect3">
        <option value='-3'>Form 3</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput3" type="text" placeholder="Form 3"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working code for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        
<script type="text/javascript">


   
function changePlaceHolder(element,target) {

    alert(element);
    
    
    if ( element == "Third") {
        jQuery(target).attr("placeholder","You did it correctly!");
    } else {
        jQuery(target).attr("placeholder","");
    }
    
}


</script>

<br><br>
    <h2>Please pick the third option from Form 1:</h2>
 
 <form id="form1">
    <select id="mySelect1" name="mySelect1" onclick="changePlaceHolder( this.value ,'#myInput1' );">
        <option value='-1'>Form 1</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput1" type="text" placeholder="Form 1"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form>


<form id="form2">
    <select id="mySelect2">
        <option value='-2'>Form 2</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput2" type="text" placeholder="Form 2"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form>

<form id="form3">
    <select id="mySelect3">
        <option value='-3'>Form 3</option>
        <option value='First'>First Choice</option>
        <option value='Second'>Second Choice</option>
        <option value='Third'>Third Choice</option>
    </select> 
    <input id="myInput3" type="text" placeholder="Form 3"></input>
    <input class="dontChangeME" type="text" placeholder="Don't Change This One!"></input>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```